# Unique validation with 2 columns - Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've been trying make my validation so that an extension must be unique to it's own company but not to other companies. Here is my DB table:

```
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained(); 
            $table->foreignId('account_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade'); 
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('extension');
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_type')->default('user');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(['extension', 'account_id'], 'unique_extension');
```

And my validation rule looks like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'editExtension.first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'editExtension.last_name' => 'required|max:255|',
            'editExtension.email' => ['required', 'email','max:255', Rule::unique('account_users', 'email')->ignore($this->editExtension->id)],
            'editExtension.extension' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::unique('account_users', 'extension', $this->client_id)->ignore($this->editExtension->id)],
            'editExtension.password' => 'required|max:255',
            'editExtension.user_type' => 'required|in:user,admin',
        ];
    }
```

But still I got errors saying that the extension number is already taken.
It seems that the Unique rule doesn't accept multiple columns, only one. Is this true?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)

#### UPDATING AN EXISTING RECORD.

*"account_users"* => **Table name**.

*"account_id", "extension"* => **The 2 fields to check for uniqueness**.

*ID of currently edited row here.* => **The id (primary key) to ignore. (The currently updated/edited table row id.)**

```php
Rule::unique("account_users")->where(
                    function ($query) use ($request) {
                        return $query->where(
                            [
                                ["account_id", "=", $request->account_id],
                                ["extension", "=", $request->extension]
                            ]
                        );
                    })->ignore(/* ID of currently edited row here. */)
```

#### CREATING A NEW RECORD.

```php
Rule::unique("account_users")->where(
                    function ($query) use ($request) {
                        return $query->where(
                            [
                                ["account_id", "=", $request->account_id],
                                ["extension", "=", $request->extension]
                            ]
                        );
                    })
```

##### Addendum

> By default, the `unique` rule will check the uniqueness of the column
> matching the name of the attribute being validated. However, you may
> pass a different column name as the second argument to the `unique`
> method:

```php
Rule::unique("account_users", "extension")->where(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I forgot to mentioned that I'm using Livewire so not sure if that makes a different.

Comment: Since I don't have a $request.
I used "$request = $this->editExtension;" which contains the information. and then made the changes you suggested.
and I got this: 
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'editExtension.extension' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `account_users` where `editExtension`.`extension` = 1234 and ((`account_id` = 16 and `extension` = 1234)))`
so, it seems that is not doing validation at all now and it's giving me a DB error.

Comment: @fanpero87,  That is good progress. Now just pass the "column name" as the second parameter to the `unique` method. Check my edited answer (_Addendum_) for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my problem!

Comment: Here is how it looks like now:
`'editExtension.extension' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::unique('account_users', 'extension')->where(function($query){return $query->where("account_id", $this->client_id);})->ignore($this->editExtension->id)],`

Comment: @fanpero87, Your changes are good enough. I'm glad you managed to figure it out.